# Disable copy assigment in CRTP-template

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm having a [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) template in which I use an object pool. Object are allocated using the generate() static method.

```
template <class tDerivedSignal, class tBridgeType, class tPayLoadType = void>
    class SignalT : public SignalSignatureT<tBridgeType>
   {
   ...
   static tDerivedSignal &generate(tPayLoadType &fPayLoad)
      {
      tDerivedSignal &rtnVal = Pool::reserve();

      // Copy pay load to signal instance
      rtnVal.mPayLoad = fPayLoad;

      // Return generated signal
      return(rtnVal);
      }
   ...
   }
```

Now, the thing is that I wan't to prevent a copy assignment like

```
DerivedSignal sig = DerivedSignal::generate()
```

The reason is that the copy ***sig*** may be have a local scope and become invalid/destructed which will generate a seg fault later on when the user tries to use it. Also, the allocated pool object will be lost and leak memory. I would like the copy assignment above to generate compile time error but a reference assignment such as

```
DerivedSignal &sig = DerivedSignal::generate()
```

shall be OK. I've tried to delete the assignment operator in the CRTP template with no luck:

```
template <class tDerivedSignal, class tBridgeType, class tPayLoadType = void>
    class SignalT : public SignalSignatureT<tBridgeType>
   {
   ...
   // Disable copy assignment operator to prevent a generated signal from being copied into
   // a new instance that is not under pool management
   tDerivedSignal operator=(const tDerivedSignal &) = delete;
   tDerivedSignal operator=(const tDerivedSignal) = delete;
   ...
   }
```

Anyone have any idea??

Comment: It's not assignment, it's copy construction. You want `tDerivedSignal(const tDerivedSignal&) = delete;`

Comment: I had the same initial idea but that won't compile on GCC 4.7. I get "expected unqualified-id before ‘const’"

Comment: Oh, sorry, got confused by something in the code, copy construction (and copy-assignment also normally) is done on the current type, so you simply want `SignalT(cont SignalT) = delete`

Comment: You should not have omitted that you use GCC 4.7. It's C++11 support was still experimental. Valid C++11 suggestions we give simply may not work.

Comment: That's a no go too since (I believe) the copy construction deletion only applies to the SignatT type and not the derived type. If I do DerivedSignal(const DerivedSignal&) = delete; it works but that kind of nullifies the purpose of the template.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, it's GCC 7.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to delete the SignalT copy assignment (and most likely copy construction).  By default, any class that inherits from this (as in  your CRTP pattern) will have its default copy constructor/copy assignement operators also deleted, which will also inhibit the default move construct/move assignment operators.

```
template <class tDerivedSignal, class tBridgeType, class tPayLoadType = void>
    class SignalT : public SignalSignatureT<tBridgeType>
   {
   ...
   // Disable copy assignment operator to prevent a generated signal from being copied into
   // a new instance that is not under pool management
   
   void SignalT operator=(const SignalT&) = delete;

   // You probably also want to delete copy construction
   SignalT(SignalT const&) =delete;

   ...
   }
```

Comment: After a minor screw up from my side the following worked:
`SignalT(SignalT const&) = delete;`
`SignalT() = default;`
The `SignalT operator=(const SignalT&) = delete` gave error (invalid abstract return type) in one of my template specializations.

Comment: You'd want to return SignalT&, to avoid that, though honestly, when I'm deleting the assignment operator, I tend to return void (a habit from C++03 days, when I would declare the function, but not define it, and make it private.